# (JavaFX)(Scene Builder) How can I make a button appear after a button is clicked?

Tags: java, button, javafx, fxml

So for some context, all I want to to do is have two buttons appear after a different button is clicked, and then those two buttons would do something when they are clicked. Any ideas?

Controller Class:

```
public class USPSCaseSpinController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        public static ImageView setUSPImage;

        @FXML
        private void handleSpinMechBack(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent handleInventoryBackParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/csgocaseopener/OpenCase.fxml"));
        Scene OPBackScene = new Scene(handleInventoryBackParent);
        Stage handleInventoryBackStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        handleInventoryBackStage.setScene(OPBackScene);
        handleInventoryBackStage.show();
        }


        @FXML
        private void SpinUSPSCase(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            Random rand = new Random();
            int gunSelect = rand.nextInt(99)+1;
            test test = new test();
            if(gunSelect<=30)
            LeadConduitUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect>=31 && gunSelect<=60)
            NightOpsUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect>=61 && gunSelect<=90)
            TorqueUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect>=91 && gunSelect<=93.5)
            GuardianUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect>=94.5 && gunSelect<=97)
            CyrexUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect>=98 && gunSelect<=99)
            CaimanUSPS(setUSPImage);
            else if(gunSelect==100)
            KillConfirmedUSPS(setUSPImage);
        }
        @FXML
        public void SetUSPImage(){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("AWPCase.png"));
        }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }   
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CaseSpinners.USPSCaseSpinController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/back.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="spinmechback" fitHeight="45.0" fitWidth="45.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSpinMechBack" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-1.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/backbtn.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="SpinUSPS" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SpinUSPSCase" text="SPIN">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <ImageView fx:id="setUSPImage" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/bprof.png" />
         </image></ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I just want the button that is already created to do what is explained above!

Comment: Do you have any code or ideas to provide? Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added the fxml file and the controller class, if you need anymore code please ask, thanks for helping!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your initial `Button` to display two other `Buttons`, and these have their own actions too, but are these actions (of the two buttons) are pre-established ? In other words you already know what these buttons will do or do you want to set their action at the runtime?

Comment: They will have a predetermined action

Comment: Basically, what you do is remove the clicked button and add the two new buttons where you want them. You should have to do this all in code, though I imagine that hiding and showing works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit vague, but I'll try to answer it as best I can.
There are several ways in which you can do this. The simplest would probably be as follows:

First, you can add define the buttons in your fxml file, and set them to be invisible by default. Just like with `SpinUSPS` you can attach an actionEvent to each of these new buttons:

```
<Button fx:id="SpinUSPS" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SpinUSPSCase" text="SPIN">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
<Button fx:id="invisible1" visible="false" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#invisibleMethod1" text="Something1"/>
<Button fx:id="invisible2" visible="false" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="340.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#invisibleMethod2" text="Something2"/>
```

When you press the `SpinUSPS` button, you want to change the visiblity of the buttons. To do this from within the `USPSCaseSpinController` class you should first define them at the top of your class:

```
@FXML
Button invisible1;
@FXML
Button invisible2;
```

Inside your `SpinUSPSCase` method you then place the following to make them visible when the `SpinUSPS` is clicked:

```
invisible1.setVisible(true);
invisible2.setVisible(true);
```

To actually make these new buttons do something you can then write action events for these new buttons:

```
@FXML
private void invisibleMethod1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    // your code goes here
}

@FXML
private void invisibleMethod2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes I actually solved this a little after I posted the question and this is exactly how I did it! I'll make sure to select this as an answer.